# Adding jar library to project Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classpath

I've tried to link a jar-library to my project, but it doesn't seem to "completely" work..

I've used Project structure (shift+ctrl+alt+S) to add stdlib.jar, and the library seems to be linked to the program module on the Modules - Dependencies tab of the Project structure window (Sorry, I can't add images, need 10 rep)

When I create a class in the src folder of the project, I can use the classes/methods from stdlib.jar, but when I create a package inside src and then create new classes inside this package, I can't use the methods from stdlib.jar.

Intellij also gives no proposals to import anything, and I don't really know what import statement should I write (if this is what I need) since stdlib.jar is the name of the jar-file, but not the package/class name.

I'm also new to programming, but this question is about how to manage Intellij Idea IDE.

It was worth 4 hours of frustration, but I couldn't find a solution.

I've read [Configuring Module Dependencies and Libraries](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html#d1262079e216), but couldn't find the exact answer for my problem. I've read many stackoverflow topics as well.

UPDATE:
Here is [the link to stdlib.jar](http://www.algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/stdlib.jar). It is from the Sedgewick's booksite on algorithms.

UPDATE2:
It really seems that stdlib.jar was designed for the default package and can't be used inside any other package (now the question is: why they do like this instead of making "universal" libraries?). But such infos are not in every book.

Comment: What is stdlib.jar and how was it created? It looks like all classes in stdlib.jar are in the default package. If a class is in the default package, it's not possible to import and use it from a different package.

Comment: Btw, the question is new, this issue was never asked on stackoverflow (at least for IDEA IDE), so why -1 I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am learning this book, too.

You simply go to "Project Structure" and then select "Modules" on the left panel, and click on the "Dependencies" tab. Add `stdlib.jar` to it, and it just works.

Comment: what scope is to be used?

Answer (score 3):

All the classes in this .jar are in the default package. Those classes can't be imported by classes in any other package; that's why IntelliJ IDEA can't resolve references to those classes and doesn't provide any auto-import suggestions.