# Can't get Stdlib.jar to work in terminal

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm coding with Java and using IntelliJ. I have imported the Stdlib.jar library using the instructions here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29640488/8304687 and it works fine in IntelliJ. But, when I run my code in the Terminal I get "cannot find symbol" errors for the methods that I'm using from Stdlib.jar.

I've tried copying all of the methods into the src file for the project I'm working on, and copying it into the main file (directory?) of my project, but none of those things have worked.

Comment: Please show your terminal command.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891 and make an executable jar with all the dependencies.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks that worked well, but I would still like to try to understand why it doesn't work how I would normally do it. I've done some research and people talk a bit about how the stdlib classes use default classes and java doesn't allow this, but I really don't understand what they're saying.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2193226/104891 and https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207703065-How-to-use-stdlib-jar-in-Intellij-Idea-.